# Should we also Stage .dll files while committing the changes to the repository?

Tags: visual-studio, github, dll, staging, resolveassemblyreference

I have five different projects in one solution. While I am staging my changes to the git repository, I am only staging my .cs and migration files and excluding all the .dll files.

When the other guy is trying to pull the solution which I had pushed before they are facing some "missing assembly reference" errors.
These errors are seems to be more hectic and frustrating.

Anyone please suggest a better solution for this  issue.

Answer (score 0):

Git being a (distributed) *source* control system, any binary built from said source should *not* be included in the repository.

Instead, they (the deliverables) should be published in a binary referential, [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) or an internal [Klondite](https://github.com/themotleyfool/Klondike), [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788247/6309), in order for another collaborator to *fetch* those dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to push the code on the master branch using the version control system on visual studio. One can also use bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/product and git commands https://github.github.com/training-kit/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf

Mabe one way is to separate the solution so that other projects dont use the same assembly references.