# Using Caliburn Micro Dependency Injection with custom ModernUI ContentLoader

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, caliburn.micro

I just started using Cliburn Micro in my wpf application. I develop using dependency injection in order to help keep things abstract using interfaces.

How can I use the Caliburn Micros Bootstrappers Container to instantiate my own instances of classes.

For example

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int ReturnNumber();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int ReturnNumber()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class SomeViewModel()
{
    public SomeViewMode()
    {
        IFoo = //instance from caliburn
    }
}
```

Within my bootstrapper I am using a CompositionContainer

----UPDATE------

I am Using Modern UI and Caliburn Micro frameworks side by side but get an null value exception in the bootstrapper at the GetInstance( Type, String ) method when the bootstrapper tried to resolve an instance for a type that contains a parameter for example IWindowManager. I believe this is due to the nature of ModernUI taking a View first approach using a content loader to communicate with Caliburn.Micro however I am struggling to find a solution that allows my bootstrapper to function properly.

Here is the configuration of the bootstrapper

```
    public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<IShellViewModel>
{
    private static CompositionContainer _container;
    ....

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        // Add New ViewLocator Rule
        ViewLocator.NameTransformer.AddRule(
            @"(?<nsbefore>([A-Za-z_]\w*\.)*)?(?<nsvm>ViewModels\.)(?<nsafter>([A-Za-z_]\w*\.)*)(?<basename>[A-Za-z_]\w*)(?<suffix>ViewModel$)",
            @"${nsbefore}Views.${nsafter}${basename}View",
            @"(([A-Za-z_]\w*\.)*)?ViewModels\.([A-Za-z_]\w*\.)*[A-Za-z_]\w*ViewModel$"
        );

        _container = new CompositionContainer(
                new AggregateCatalog(
                new AssemblyCatalog( typeof( IShellViewModel ).Assembly ),
                AssemblySource.Instance.Select( x => new AssemblyCatalog( x ) ).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>().FirstOrDefault()
            )
        );

        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>( new WindowManager() );
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>( new EventAggregator() );
        _container.Compose( batch );
    }

    protected override object GetInstance( Type serviceType, string key )
    {
        string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty( key ) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName( serviceType ) : key;

        var exports = _container.GetExportedValues<object>( contract );
        return exports.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

You could inject your dependency via constructor injection (assuming it is a required dependency):

```
public class SomeViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IFoo foo;

    public SomeViewModel(IFoo foo)
    {
       // Can use foo later, e.g. in OnActivate for your screen
       this.foo = foo;            
    }
}
```

The Caliburn.Micro generic bootstrapper resolves the your root view model (e.g. `ShellViewModel`) via the configured container. If `SomeViewModel` is a dependency of `ShellViewModel`, then all of it's dependencies will be resolved by the container also, and any further chained dependencies.

If you wish to control the lifetime of types, then inject a factory instead that is registered in your container, and create new instances of that type via the factory.

Comment: Hi I am a large user of construction injection as have used Ninject as my primary framework in the past, however this project is to be developed using ModernUI and Caliburn Micro. I have a bootstrapper that works as long as I don't use any parameters in the ViewModel Constructor. With a parameter any ViewModel that's instances is resolved by the Bootstrapper but loaded through a MUI content Loader throws an exeption in the GetInstance() method of the Bootstrapper. Any thoughts on why that might be? I will update my question above to show an example, thanks again.

Comment: You could create a custom content loader that uses the Caliburn.Micro view model locator (which resolves view models via the configured container). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421582/caliburn-micro-and-modernui-examples-tutorials. Alternatively, you might consider a UI framework that supports a view model first approach, such as MahApps.Metro - http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/.

Comment: I am actually using a Custom Loader, nearly the same as that post (already looked at that in the past). Sadly using MahApps is not an option.

Comment: haha I'm an utter tool! After going through the documentation on CM again I noticed I was missed the [ImportingConstructor] attribute above the class

Comment: Yes that would do it! It's actually MEF that requires the attribute for types without a default parameterless constructor.

Comment: Thanks for your help though devdigital :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution to this problem so thought I would post it for any one else. By defualt Caliburn.Micro looks for a default constructor containing no parameters but that does not exist in the class. So the [ImportingConstructor] attribute needs to be used to tell caliburn micro to build an instance of the class using injection to fill the parameters.

Example using devdigitals example

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public class SomeViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IFoo foo;

    public SomeViewModel(IFoo foo)
    {
       // Can use foo later, e.g. in OnActivate for your screen
       this.foo = foo;            
    }
}
```