# Install multiple NuGet packages at once

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Is it possible to use nuget to install multiple packages at once? That is, both download all nuget packages listed in `packages.config` **and** add the packages to the `.csproj` file.

What I do now is to use the **NuGet Package Manager** in Visual Studio and install each package one by one, but is there an easier way?

**EDIT:**
This question is not solved by [How do I get NuGet to install/update all the packages in the packages.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876732/how-do-i-get-nuget-to-install-update-all-the-packages-in-the-packages-config) as it only downloads and installes the packages to the `packages` directory, and does not change the project files.

If I run

```
nuget install packages.config
```

It will install all packages in the `packages.config` file, but not update the project file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get NuGet to install/update all the packages in the packages.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876732/how-do-i-get-nuget-to-install-update-all-the-packages-in-the-packages-config)

Comment: It sounds like what you want is when you create a brand new project, you just want to copy a packages.config into the folder and execute the *nuget install packages.config* and get it to update the project file as well. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @BlackFrog Yes, that is correct. After I copied packages.config, I ran `Update-Package -reinstall` as suggested by @Zidad in the answer below. And that worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could you try to run this from the package manager console in Visual Studio:

```
Update-Package –reinstall
```

That should fix missing assembly references in your `*.csproj` files, if the packages are already in your `packages.config`.

Comment: You may also need to use `-projectName` flag to select particular project. Otherwise, packages will be reinstalled in all projects in a solution.