# ASP.NET : The compiler failed with error code -532462766 - Rider

Tags: c#, blazor, rider

I'mg using Rider.

I want to watch my project I got this error:

```
Error Number:-1,State:0,Class:20

dotnet watch ❌ Exited with error code -532462766
dotnet watch ⏳ Waiting for a file to change before restarting dotnet...
```

I'm using asp.net core 6.
[image]

Comment: There is a different question about this error code with ASP.NET: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43328087/1843468 Does this help?

Comment: Why do you say the compiler failed? There's not much to go on, but the output looks like the program was compiled and run, but then exited, probably due to an exception.