# Reinstall all nuget packages from command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, nuget

I am doing a restore within a batch file but when I open the projects I still see stuff missing so I have to run an `update-package -reinstall` on each solution. Is there a way to do this with command? I cannot find it anywhere in 2 days of googling :/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14643519/1035521

Comment: thank you but I need to run this inside a batch file. right now i run the Restore via command but i still have to open the solution and run the -reinstall to catch what was not restored.