# Update NuGet packages programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget

I've seen many questions and examples about installing `NuGet` packages, but not one about updating packages.

What's the best way to update `NuGet` packages? I'm trying to do this from a `ASP.NET MVC` application to update packages in a `UWP` project which has `projec.json` for packages references.

Do I need to update `.csproj` and `project.json` files as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876732/how-do-i-get-nuget-to-install-update-all-the-packages-in-the-packages-config  There is some data about Update, restore packages, etc.. please check if this help you.

Comment: Or you can use tools to do the trick , like https://github.com/davidfowl/NuGetPowerTools

Comment: Thanks, but none of them were useful. Notice that I'm trying to this programmatically (from C# code)

Comment: couldn't you run the nuget cli via command-line in code? e.g. using Process https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I could, but after it starts, there's no results, meaning I can't know if anything went wrong or did it succeed, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling with `NuGet.VisualStudio` and `NuGet.Core` packages and spending so much time, I've found out that the best approach is to use NuGet CLI and .NET `Process` object. After downloading `nuget.exe` this is how to update packages:

```
            var updateOutput = new List<string>();
            var updateError = new List<string>();
            var updateProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "the path to nuget.exe file",
                    Arguments = "update " + "project path including .csproj file",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            updateProcess.Start();
            while (!updateProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                updateOutput.Add(updateProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            }
            while (!updateProcess.StandardError.EndOfStream)
            {
                updateError.Add(updateProcess.StandardError.ReadLine());
            }
```

After that what you do with `updateOutput` and `updateError` is your decision based on your needs.

**Note:** In my case I had `project.json` for package configuration and `nuget.exe` needed `packages.config` file. So, I created a temporary `packages.config` file and after updating packages I deleted it. Like this:

```
            var ProjectPath = "the path to project folder";
            var input = new StringBuilder();
            input.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
            input.AppendLine("<packages>");

            using (var r = new StreamReader(ProjectPath + @"\project.json"))
            {
                var json = r.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                foreach (var item in array.dependencies)
                {
                    var xmlNode = item.ToString().Split(':');
                    input.AppendLine("<package id=" + xmlNode[0] + " version=" + xmlNode[1] + " />");
                }
            }
            input.AppendLine("</packages>");

            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(input.ToString());
            doc.Save(ProjectPath + @"\packages.config");
            // After updating packages
            File.Delete(ProjectPath + @"\packages.config");
```