# Missing assembly references

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, assemblies

I have cleaned the solution. Even deleted contents of the bin folder. But I still get

> Type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exists in the namespace 'System.Web'
>
> The type or namespace name 'Kendo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image: Error Console showing all the errors]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: firstly check all errors, cause sometimes one small error (not related to assembly)  creates such issues

Comment: Try from cmd `nuget install packages.config` or `nuget restore YourSolution.sln` or from PM `Update-Package -Reinstall` or even Right click on the Solution node in Solution Explorer and select Enable NuGet Package Restore.- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876732/how-do-i-get-nuget-to-install-update-all-the-packages-in-the-packages-config/18577412

Comment: solution-right click-restore packages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the references needed.Install MVC, Kendo, etc. again and the references will be added to your project.

Either browse for the necessary packages (Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution) or install it using the Nuget console (Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console)

Answer (score 0):

Try Cata Hotea's solution.  I can't tell if you have the reference from your screenshot.  It stops. Once System.Web.Mvc is installed.  Clean your solution. Close your project.  Go to the file system.  Delete everything within the packages directory.  Then delete your hidden .vs.  Then open the solution again within VS. You should get a pop up about needing to download the packages or you can just build the project.  Also, be sure to add your Kendo.Mvc reference to the Web.config within your Views directory in XML tag system.web -> pages -> namespaces -> add. Also, note adding or changing System.Web.Mvc or Razor does not always update the Web.config version numbers. Be sure those are correct to avoid warnings.