# Updating nuget package and all its dependencies at once

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-update

I just created a new .net core with Angular project and there are already some NuGet packages like "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions"  with updates available.

When I try to update it there is an error that says that there is a version conflict with another package "Microsoft.ApNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions", that to solve this problem i need to install or reference "Microsoft.ApNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" 2.2.0, when i try to install it then a similar error appears about another dependency and so on.

Is there a way to make nuget update/install all of those dependencies at once instead of me installing them one by one?

Comment: What framework does your project target? .net core2.2 or .net core3.0, and which way do you update the packages, I create a asp.net core with Angular project but it seems the packages mentioned above are not referenced directly.

Comment: Is net core 2.1, And  the update for "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" is listed in nuget package manager under updates, the other ones are not listed in npm, but he error asks me to install them or reference them.
I tried installing them using the console and in the UI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to make nuget update/install all of those dependencies
>   at once instead of me installing them one by one?

**By Command-line:**
You can download [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/downloads),and add the path where it exists to **Path** system environment variables. Then you could simply reference the `nuget.exe` directly. After that you can use command like `nuget update YourSolution.sln` in [Package Manager Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell) to update the dependencies for solution. More details see [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6882750/10910450) in a similar issue. Thanks to him!

**In VS IDE:** Right-click project name in `Solution Explorer`=>`Manage Nuget Packages`, in **Updates** lab you can choose `Select all packages` and `Update` Button.

[image]

> But one point you may need to know is the update action you've done is
>   not suggested for this situation.

All above is to answer your question about the way to easily update or install all dependencies. But actually you're **not supposed to update** the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` package in your project. You're developing a project that targets `.net core 2.1` instead of `.net core 2.2`. So when you create a new `.net core2.1 with Angular project`, these nuget packages designed in the template whose version is 2.1.X is enough, you **don't need to** update them to .net core2.2 or higher.

You're in a asp .net core 2.1 project, and it depends on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` 2.1.X, check its dependencies you can find something like this:

[image]

I think that's why it threw `version conflicts` error message, so what's the special reason you update the package in this situation? You can install .net core 2.2 SDK [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks). And then you can create the project that targets .net core2.2 and reference those AspNetCore-related packages with version 2.2.x in your project. If I misunderstand anything, please feel free to correct me:)

Comment: Oh, I see, so that's why I got all those errors. I tried updating them because it was needed to install the latest EntityFrameworkCore, but then i will install an older one because of the SDK I'm Using. Thanks!