# .NetFrame 4.8 upgrade and Method not found: 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upgrade, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

We are in middle of upgrading our pre-production environment from 4.0 to 4.8 .net framework. After upgrade we are seeing following error as soon as you open the site,

[image]

Although this error can be fixed if we modify **web.config** file manually from,

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

To,

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

What I am curious to know if we can avoid web.config updates and yet upgrade to 4.8 because this is going to be a nightmare for production upgrade for more than 1000 sites.

Please advise!

Comment: How are you upgrading, exactly? And how are you deploying afterwards?

Comment: By changing our projects to point to new framework in project properties. Rest visual studio takes care of every other change. Deployment would be from master branch to production environment refresh.

Comment: Try reinstalling all NuGet packages after that, which will force the binding redirects to be regenerated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876732/how-do-i-get-nuget-to-install-update-all-the-packages-in-the-packages-config

Comment: Do you suggest to run Install-Package -Reinstall -All in production environment ? We are still going to keep 4.0 framework in our IIS.

Comment: But if you mean you have many sites whose web.config is sacred and must not be touched, then you have a whole nother problem which you must address immediately. After you've taken backup/deployment steps, then you could update them with a PowerShell RegRex script.

Comment: No, not in production. After upgrading the framework, do `Update-Package -Reinstall` to fix the web.config. Then deploy the upgraded site with said config.

Comment: I did run the command, and it generates in my development environment. However, my concern is more related to upgrading pre-prod/prod sites where web.config files doesnt upgrade from the master. If someone has to be change, it must happen manually.

Comment: That's what I meant by my earlier comment: that is problematic. What would you do if the server's disk crashed? What if you have another update that requires a new or changed config value? If you can't update your configs from your deployment system, you'll have to script the update. Some PowerShell (and rigorous testing and backups) should get you a long way.

Comment: Its not me but added by stackoverflow